# how to make table for pdf_export with python pandas

Tags: python, pandas, pdf-generation, zabbix

I have Json file, that is attachet as example.json. My question is, how to make 2 tables with [pdf_exports](https://edinburgh-genome-foundry.github.io/pdf_reports/index.html)

**Table 1**

```
| Servername | Count of unresolved problems |
| ---------- | ---------------------------- |
| Server1    | 1                            |
| Server2    | 2                            |
```

**Table 2**

```
| Servername | Problem description          | Occurency |
| ---------- | ----------------------------------------------------------------- | -- |
| Server1    | More than 100 items having missing data for more than 10 minutes  | 1 |
| Server2    | Zabbix data sender processes more than 75% busy | 1 |
```

Both tables can have unpredictable rows.

**Json Example**

```
[
  {
    "Basic_info": {
      "host": "Server1.domain.example",
      "hostid": "10315",
      "name": "Server1"
    },
    "Problems": {
      "Count events by trigger": {
        "More than 100 items having missing data for more than 10 minutes": 1
      },
      "Count of unresolved problems": 1
    },
    "Technical_info": {
      "Available memory": "2.78 GB",
      "Free disk space on /": "47.82 GB",
      "Free disk space on /boot": "709.49 MB",
      "Free disk space on /home": "56.66 GB",
      "Total disk space on /": "49.98 GB",
      "Total disk space on /boot": "1014.0 MB",
      "Total disk space on /home": "56.69 GB",
      "Total memory": "3.63 GB",
      "Used disk space on /": "2.16 GB",
      "Used disk space on /boot": "304.51 MB",
      "Used disk space on /home": "32.22 MB"
    }
  },
  {
    "Basic_info": {
      "host": "Server2.domain.example",
      "hostid": "10415",
      "name": "Server2"
    },
    "Problems": {
      "Count events by trigger": {
        "Zabbix data sender processes more than 75% busy": 1
      },
      "Count of unresolved problems": 0
    },
    "Technical_info": {
      "Available memory": "6.43 GB",
      "Free disk space on /": "52.75 GB",
      "Free disk space on /boot": "653.87 MB",
      "Free disk space on /home": "52.01 GB",
      "Total disk space on /": "55.64 GB",
      "Total disk space on /boot": "975.9 MB",
      "Total disk space on /home": "52.41 GB",
      "Total memory": "7.48 GB",
      "Used disk space on /": "2.89 GB",
      "Used disk space on /boot": "254.83 MB",
      "Used disk space on /home": "406.46 MB"
    }
  }
]
```

Comment: you might want to check if https://github.com/martinm76/zabbix-pdf-report does what you need

Comment: Thank you @IronBishop, but I want to learn work with python and pandas module more. I have valid json with data collected from zabbix api. I need put this data to table as I describe bottom. I think, I dont understand what is pandas working. I have tried a lot of tutorials, youtube videos, but i think something Im doing wrong.